# Understanding `getArgs`

Tags: haskell

I expect the following `GetArgs.hs` to print out the arguments passed into it.

```
import System.Environment

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    print args
```

But, after loading it in `ghci`, I get the following error:

```
ghci> main 3 4 3

<interactive>:39:1:
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> t0'
                with actual type `IO ()'
    The function `main' is applied to three arguments,
    but its type `IO ()' has none
    In the expression: main 3 4 3
    In an equation for `it': it = main 3 4 3
```

Since `print` has this type:

ghci> :t print
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()

I would've expected `print args` to have worked.

Why not?

Comment: Try `:main 3 4 3`. Better yet, compile your program and run it from the command-line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`print args` works fine. What doesn't work is `main 3 4 3`. `main` doesn't take any argument, but you're trying to call it with three.

If you want to simulate calling your program with command line parameters from ghci, you can use the `:main` command (with a colon in front). Alternatively you can compile your program and actually run it from the command lines with the given arguments.

Answer (score 11):

While in ghci use the run command

> :run main 3 4 3

Comment: +1 for `:run`. I knew about `:main` but not this one.